# how to animate the character with body motion using asus xtion pro

Tags: c#, animation, asus-xtion

my final year project is to animate `.fbx` (skeleton) with **Asus Xtion Pro Live** 
just like that in the video below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxbH-QDHAVg

I had downloaded miku miku dance file and also used it. but I am not able to load the `.fbx` file into it.

My question is: 
*how to animate the character(`.fbx` file) just like in the video using **c#** with **Asus Xtion Pro Live**?*

Comment: Any code samples to show? What is the exact error messag you get?

Comment: i had downloaded the MMD software and in that face and lips application, i  tried to import files, and the import file format support only PMD format.                   (importanly i had not started the coding)is there is any tutorial for animate .fbx skeleton with the joints in asus xtion pro live